# Does module Process have a private instance method 'wait'?

Tags: ruby, module, process, include

A few days ago, when I looked up my Dash documents, I found a weird ruby code snippet.

```
include Process
fork { exit 99 }                 #=> 27429
wait                             #=> 27429
$?.exitstatus                    #=> 99
```

The thing shocked me is why the Object class get the 'wait' instance method when it include the Process mudule. the Process module has only a class method 'wait' as the document indicated.

Comment: `wait` is defined as a [module function](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Ruby stdlib modules are written in a way that allows one to use either:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p
```

or

```
include FileUtils
mkdir_p
```

This is done by using [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function):

```
module FileUtils
  def mkdir_p(*args)
    ...
  end
  module_function :mkdir_p
end
```

This makes it possible to use the method as a class method with `FileUtils.mkdir_p` and as an instance method `mkdir_p` when included. It makes the instance method private when included:

```
class Foo
  include FileUtils

  def test
    mkdir_p
  end
end

Foo.mkdir_p # => NoMethodError (undefined method `mkdir_p`...
Foo.new.mkdir_p # => NoMethodError (private method `mkdir_p`...
Foo.new.test # => no problem there
```

It's also possible to make module functions private by using `module_function` together with `private_class_method`:

```
module AlarmClock
  def is_it_time?
    morning_yet?
  end
  module_function :is_it_time?

  def morning_yet?
    (7..11).cover?(Time.now.hour)
  end
  module_function :morning_yet?
  private_class_method :morning_yet?
end
```

Now you have a public module function which uses a private module function and your module is still includable and usable in another class/module:

```
AlarmClock.morning_yet? # => NoMethodError (private method `morning_yet?' ..
AlarmClock.is_it_time? # => true

class WristWatch
  include AlarmClock

  def start_beeping
    return "beep" if is_it_time?
  end

  def stop_beeping
    return "silence" if !morning_yet?
  end
end

WristWatch.new.morning_yet? # => NoMethodError (private ..
WristWatch.new.is_it_time? # => NoMethodError (private ..
WristWatch.new.start_beeping => "beep"
WristWatch.new.stop_beeping "silence"
```

Some stdlib modules have a helper method for not having to write two extra lines, for example [fileutils.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/36b183ce8c80eb46942c2078fc016a4204f28889/lib/fileutils.rb#L98-L101):

```
module FileUtils
  def self.private_module_function(name)   #:nodoc:
    module_function name
    private_class_method name
  end
  ...
end
```

`Process` is built-in and written in C, so it does not come from something like `process.rb`, but I assume it has been written in a similiar manner.

Comment: excepting the fact that `Dir` is a ruby core `Class` and will raise a `TypeError` declaring it as a `Module`

Answer (score -1):

Wait is an instance method of class Concurrent::Event which in turn is inherting from Module whose superclass is Object, thus you are able to access wait method.

For Reference:

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent%2FEvent:wait.

Comment: His code and question has nothing to do with concurrent-ruby.